# JS: event handler to have only one section triggered

Tags: javascript, css

I am adding event handler to each bar which will toggle the class and extend/retract the height.  This does this to each one so I can have multiple sections expanded at once.  How can I change this code to have it where if I click on one bar and another is expanded, it will automatically retract that height and expand the new one only -- so that only one is expanded at a time.

https://codepen.io/Mariomario2/pen/JjRGJVr

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .cont {
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .label {
            width: 93px;
            height: 50px;
            background:blue;
            transition: height 600ms ease-in;
        }
        .label.foo {
            transition: height 600ms ease-in;
            height: 90px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="label"></div>
        <div class="label"></div>
        <div class="label"></div>
        <div class="label"></div>

    </div>
    <script>
        let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
        console.log(labels)
        labels.forEach(label => {
            label.onclick = (evt) => {
                console.log(evt.target.classList.toggle('foo'))
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Loop over the `labels` and find any that have the `foo` class that are not the one that was clicked.  For all of them that match that, which should be just one, remove the `foo` class.  Since it's just one, you can probably use the `find()` method

Comment: Add this `[...labels].filter(lbl => lbl !== label).forEach(lbl => lbl.classList.remove("foo"))` before `console.log(evt.target.classList.toggle('foo'))`

Comment: thanks @ptothep ..I guess a nested forEach is the only way this could work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
label.onclick = (evt) => {
    evt.target.classList.toggle('foo');
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.label.foo'))
       .find(label => label !== evt.target)
       .classList.remove('foo');
}
```

So you find the label that's opened and not the current target then close it

Comment: wouldnt you need to wrap a forEach around that to apply the onclick to each label?

Comment: Definitely. I just grabbed the innermost relevant part of your code...